# MySql - PHP Retrieving Info displays every other column

Tags: php, mysql

I am retrieving information from the database and displaying it in a table, However i have noticed i only retrieve some and not all columns, It seems to be in 2s i.e:
No2, No 4, No6, No8 etc all show up correctly, but no 1, no 3, no5 doesnt show up at all, How would i solve this my retrieving code is:

```
include ("mysqldb.php");
$out = mysqli_query ($dbc, "SELECT * FROM `User-Comments`");
echo "<table align='center' border='1' cellspacing='3' cellpadding='3' width= '75%'>
    <tr> 
        <td align='left'><b>Comments</b></td>
    </tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($out)){
    echo "<tr>
        <td align='left>".$row ['Usercom']."</td>
        </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Is it a problem with my markup?.

Comment: You do have the ending </table> right as it's not show above.

Comment: Yes, forgot to add that bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An apostrophe (`'`) is missing on this line:

```
        <td align='left>".$row ['Usercom']."</td>
```

after "left".

Answer (score -1):

Other than what others pointed out, let us go directly to the Query..

```
SELECT * FROM `User-Comments.
```

That is all you have. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `User-Comments` ORDER BY UserCom ASC
```

Comment: This isn't an answer - the query itself is perfectly valid (albeit less specific than what you stated).